# Displaying a foreignkey's value

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

So I have a model like this:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    show = models.ForeignKey("Show")

class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Inside my SeasonAdmin I can see that the show field has a dropdown box for the list of Shows, but the problem is that when I click on the dropdown box I just see a list of `Show object`. How would I make it show the object name instead of just `Show object`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str) method:

```
class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```